# Eloquent one to many relationship not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm stuck for hours with one of those issues where a fresh set of eyes might help. I just can't understand what's missing.

I'm connecting a model called `User_ativo` and defining two **one-to-many** relations to models `Instituicao` and `Tipo_Ativo`.

My database is simple.
Table `user_ativo` has columns "tipo_ativo_id" and "instituicao_id". I have a test row where both are set to 1. Both my tables `instituicoes` and `tipo_ativos` have only "id" and a string field "nome" (name). Both have a record with id == 1.

**User_ativo.php:**

```
<?php

  namespace App;

  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  class User_ativo extends Model
  {
    public function tipo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tipo_ativo');
    }

    public function instituicao(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Instituicao');
    }
  }
```

**Instituicao.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Instituicao extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'instituicoes';

    public function user_ativos(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User_ativo');
    }
}
```

**Tipo_ativo.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tipo_ativo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tipo_ativos';

    public function user_ativos(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User_ativo');
    }
}
```

My **controller** method that fetches the date goes as follow:

```
public function index()
{
    $ativos = User_ativo::with('tipo', 'instituicao')->get();
    return view('ativos.index', compact('ativos'));
}
```

Now here's where it gets interesting, for some reason I can't figure out, when I echo the $ativos variable in my view I get this:

```
 [{"id":1,"user_id":1,"instituicao_id":1,"tipo_ativo_id":1,"tipo":null,"instituicao":{"id":1,"nome":"Banco do Brasil"}}]
```

So, weirdly my relationship with the `Instituicao` model works, but the one with `Tipo_ativo` returns **null**.

I'm pretty confident someone will point out some dumb and obvious mistake in all of this, but I can't for the life of me understand why one works and the other doesn't since they're pretty much the same thing.

Comment: try this :   $ativos = User_ativo::with('tipo')->with('instituicao')->get();

Comment: @InzamamIdrees no luck, unfortunately.

Comment: show you tables structure

Comment: Try adding the forign key to the relation in user model public function tipo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tipo_ativo', 'tipo_ativo_id');
    }

Comment: Read this post, I think possible duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869249/clarify-how-to-setup-a-one-to-many-relationship-in-laravels-eloquent-orm?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relationships names are not according to laravel convention.
Read below function and provide `foreign_key` and `local_key/owner_key` to your relationships then it will work

```
public function belongsTo($related, $foreignKey = null, $ownerKey = null, $relation = null){}
```

If we do not follow laravel convention while creating relationships then we have to  tell it that these are the foreign and local keys that should be used. 
[Read more here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

```
class User_ativo extends Model{
    public function tipo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tipo_ativo','user_ativo_id'); //second parameter is foreign_key_of_User_avito_table_here
    }

    public function instituicao(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Instituicao','user_ativo_id'); //second parameter is foreign_key_of_User_avito_table_here
    }
}


class Instituicao extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'instituicoes';

    public function user_ativos(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User_ativo','instituicao_id'); //second parameter is foreign key of Instituicao model 
    }
}


class Tipo_ativo extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tipo_ativos';

    public function user_ativos(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\User_ativo','tipo_ativo_id'); //second parameter is foreign key of Tipo_ativo model.
    }
}
```

Comment: That's right, I've made some tests and just to be clear my options were either to manually inform the foreign key `tipo_ativo_id` or to change the method `tipo()` on `User_ativo` to `tipo_ativo`. My bad, I knew it was a dumb question, but I was stuck for way too long trying to identify my mistake.

Comment: I thought that the unorthodox function name might have been the issue, but then I assumed it recognized the informed table name on the `Tipo_ativo` model to infer the foreign key name instead of inferring it from the function `tipo()`